# How to getEntityManager()  from outside model/controller?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to use Symfony 2 with Doctrine 2. But I have following problem: 
after creating class that in fact is neither controller nor model, I wanted to use there getEntityManager(). But how can I get this?

Thx in advance.

Answer (score 7):

You need to define this class a a service and then pass entity manager as an argument (either inside constructor or via setter).

For more info take a look at [Service Container documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/master/book/service_container.html).

Something like this:

```
services:
    my_hello_class:
        class:        Acme\HelloBundle\HelloClass
        arguments:    ["@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"]
```

And then the class would look like this:

```
// ....

class HelloClass
{
    private $em;

    public function __construct(\Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager $em)
    {
        $this->em = $em; 

        // ....
    }   

}
```

Comment: Ok, and an instance of that class is set by using `$this->('my_hello_class')` , but how do you access that outside of a model/controller when `$this` is not a model/controller?